# Synchronized , volatile and thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, volatile

I am reading some books about java concurrency lately. Regarding thread safety, if it is not possible to make a class inmutable, you can always ensure thread safety by synchronizing its data.

The following class would be clearly not thread safe

```
public class NotThreadSafe {
  private int value;

  public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

Then i can synchronize the write, but it will remain not thread safe

```
public class StillNotThreadSafe {
  private int value;

  public synchronized void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

As i would need to synchronize not only the writes, but also the reads

```
public class ThreadSafe {
  private int value;

  public synchronized void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public synchronized int getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

Now the question is, by using volatile I can guarantee that other threads will see the updated value, so this makes me think that this class should be thread safe

```
public class NotSure {
  private volatile int value;

  public synchronized void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

Is the last class thread-safe??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Yes, but you don't even need `synchronized` in that last case. The only thing `setValue` does is a *single* operation, a write -- and volatiles are atomic within each operation. That is, each write is atomic, and each read is atomic.

**Longer answer:**

Of course, if you were to try to increment the value using a pattern like:

```
NotSure ns = new NotSure();
int v = ns.getValue();
ns.setValue(v + 1);
```

... then that is *not* thread-safe, since it involves two operations on `ns.value` (a read and a write), whereas `volatile` only gives you atomicity for one operation. In this case, even adding `synchronized` to *both* the getter and setter wouldn't be enough, since operations could be injected between both method invocations.

That last point is actually a bit of a counter-argument to the claim that "you can always ensure thread safety by synchronizing [an object's] data." If you wanted a thread-safe way to increment `NotSure.value`, you'd need to synchronize that whole increment operation, not just access to the object's data. And in that case, you *would* need to synchronize the setter, since it could otherwise interject itself between the increment method's operations. The getter still wouldn't need to be synchronized, since the `volatile` keyword would ensure that the getter gets either the pre-incremented or post-incremented value.

Comment: Assume setValue() does a little more than that (say setting 100 variables) and it is not completed in first thread's timeslice. Now, if the second thread starts to read, how will declaring all the variables as volatile help?. Like you said, Volatile is atomic. So, now, the second thread will be forced to ignore its local cache. It is forced to get the latest value. If you dont use synchronized in this case, half the values that are updated by the first thread are read right?. And we wouldnt want that, would we?. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Correct, I was referring to `setValue` as written in the question. If that method did more -- if it set multiple values, or even wrote to `value` multiple times -- then without `synchronized`, a getter (or other method) could come through and read values as they are halfway through `setValue`'s execution, which would probably be bad. At that point, it all really depends on the specific methods, fields, use case/requirements, etc.

Comment: Use a lock or synchronize on a monitor object if the operations are more complex.

Answer (score 0):

True there is no specific need for making the methods getValue or setValue as synchronized.

I would suggest making the variable value as synchronized.

getter or setter call can be made at the same time. In case calling from two separate thread (one doing getter call and other doing setter call.

making the object or data which is being accessed we may be able to make it thread safe.

Comment: A variable/field can't be synchronized, only a method or block can be.

Comment: by that I mean synchroized(value) something like -----------          Integer valx = 0;
 
 int getValx()               
 {
  synchronized(valx)
  {
   return valx;
  }
 }
 
 void setValx(int valX)
 {
  synchronized(valx)
  {
   valx = valX;
  }
 } -------- It seems we cannot do synchronized on primitive data types

Comment: That's not thread-safe, either. Remember, in order for `synchronized` to work, both invocations need to be on the same object. If you start out with `Integer valx = 0` and then call `setValx(1)`, then the next time you invoke `setValx` or `getValx`, you could be invoking it on a _different_ object, `valx = 1`. So the two calls aren't synchronized with respect to each other -- it's not thread-safe.

Comment: Specifically, if threadA is what calls `setValx(1)`, then from its perspective `valx` was assigned as `valx = 0; valx = 1`. The system can reorder operations such that threadB sees the assignments as `valx = 1; valx = 0`. In this case, threadB's invocation of `getValx` is synchronized against `Integer(1)`, and is thus not synchronized with respect to `setValx` (which is synchronized against `Integer(0)`). At this point, it can read `valx == 1` _or_ it can have the reordered `valx = 0` assignment race in (since there's no synchronization). In other words, it can read `valx == 0`!